# Solving an antiderivative via u-substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have a density function defined as $f(x) = (1/10) \exp(-x/10)$.  The answer to the solution suggests that the antiderivative, the cumulative distribution function, ought to be $\exp(-x/10)$, however my own attempts at arriving at the solution results in $(1/10) \exp(-x/10)$ as the solution.

What am I not taking into consideration?

Comment: $$F_{X}(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f_{X}(t)\mathrm{d}t = \int_{0}^{x}\theta e^{-\theta x} = 1 - e^{-\theta x}$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $-\exp(-x/10)$?

Comment: Since $F_{X}(x) = \mathbb{P}(X\leq x) \geq 0$, $-\exp(-x/10) < 0$ cannot be its expression.

Comment: An antiderivative is a function, you cannot *solve* a function.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia, I only said that it is impossible to *solve* a function (or a number, or a letter, or a hamburger).

Comment: @Alexey I think there has been a misunderstanding (from my part) then. I thought you had addressed the question to me.

Comment: If the derivative of $F(x)$ is $f(x)$ then the derivative of $-F(-bx)$ is $bf(-bx)$ by the chain rule.  So in reverse $\int_0^y bf(-bx) \, dx =\left. -F(-bx)\right|^y_0 = -F(-by)+F(0)$ and here $b=\frac1{10}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the integral (antiderivative)
$$
\int \frac{1}{10} e^{-\frac{1}{10}x} dx
$$
If we set $u=-\frac{1}{10}x$, then we need to change $dx$ to its equivalent form  for our variable $u$. Here we can write
$$
\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} \left( -\frac{1}{10}x \right) = -\frac{1}{10}
$$
From here we can say that
$$
dx = -10du
$$
So we can substitute this into out integral to write
$$
\int \frac{1}{10} e^u (-10du) = \int -e^u du = -\int e^u du = -e^u + C
$$
We substitute back in the expression for $u$ to get
$$
-e^{-\frac{1}{10}x} + C
$$

Comment: Nice.  I can see now that I was not correctly solving for $du$.  But one thing that remains unclear to me is how we go from $-exp(u) + c$ to $exp(u) + c$.  Do we drop the negative because probabilities can only take on positive values?

Comment: My mistake, the final answer is corrected